Major discordance between uncertainties estimated by `predictInterval()` and `bootMer()` for binomial GLMM with cloglog link
We have been using predictInterval() from the merTools package to bootstrap uncertainty for binomial GLMM models (complementary log-log link), as part of a larger project analysing abundance trends of Indian bird species. (See this methodology preprint or our website for more context.)
Because of the complexity of our analyses and the size of our dataset, we chose predictInterval() over bootMer() to estimate uncertainty in our model estimates. When trying to rerun our 2023 analyses this year with updated data, however, we realised that the function now gives wildly different/unexpected uncertainty estimates---unusual compared both with last year's values as well as with bootMer() values with current data. The difference is rather "significant", with predictInterval() giving uncertainties that are larger by an order of 10 (in the reprex, 0.058 vs 0.616). For our 2023 analysis, we had used merTools 0.6.1 and this time we used merTools 0.6.2. Although we couldn't find any obvious culprit from the version history of merTools, we still tried to rerun using 0.6.1. Interestingly, this also now produces unusual SEs.
We have been unable to figure out what could be causing this stark discrepancy. From our testing so far, there has been no internal change in our code or data that could be linked to this. It is interesting that bootstrapped mean estimates seem totally unaffected, and it's just the SEs that have changed. In fact, we also faced this same issue in another independent project that also analyses bird abundance trends from eBird data.
Assuming this has something to do with the differences in statistical approaches between the two functions, we are posting here on CrossValidated, but happy to move this to a GitHub issue or to StackOverflow if needed. Considering that bootMer() simply isn't a pragmatic solution for our usecase, we would greatly appreciate any help and look forward to having predictInterval() work fine again!
Reprex
This GitHub repository has everything required to reproduce our issue, including the input data in reprex_pred_lwdu.RData. The script soib_reprex.R reproduces our exact issue, just with a smaller subset of our real data (for faster compute). sim_reprex.R uses a simulated dataset to run a similar model and compare bootstrapped estimates, but the discrepancy there is not much more than is to be expected in general. This could be because the simulation doesn't capture our data characteristics well enough. Finally, test_versions.R tries to use merTools 0.6.1 to check if those estimates are "normal" (but they are not).
System specs
This current testing has been done on a Linux system with 16 GB RAM, 8 cores, and an Intel i5 processor, running R 4.4.2 and RStudio 2024.09.0. On this system, the predictInterval() calls take hardly a second each, while the bootMer() calls with 10 sims take ~60 sec for the subsetted data (to 100,000 rows), without parallelisation. (However, the discrepancy has arisen in multiple machines running various Windows OS configurations.)

wondering about https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/47, https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/762

Is it straightforward to fit the model in a Bayesian way via brms? Sometimes what is going on becomes clearer if you do that, as you can then also see things like which underlying (perhaps latent) random effects variables have changed (e.g. you might have some extreme outlier observations that get huge latent random effects and thus drive up the estimates of the random effects variance).
